# how to ignore nan values and calculate mean of last 3 months

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have uploaded 6 months data Jul - Dec

This is my dictionary data

```
print(UPI_TransferIn)
```

output:

```
[{'UPI TransferIn amt': 3000.0, 'date': '11-10-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 560.0, 'date': '25-09-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 3000.0, 'date': '14-09-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 6984.0, 'date': '09-07-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}]
```

**My Code**

```
    Avg_per_month = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).mean()                                                             
    Avg_of_3_Month = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).mean().last("3M")
    total_Avg_of_3_Months = Avg_of_3_Month['UPI TransferIn amt'].mean()              

    print("\nAverage UPI Transaction-In per month :\n ", Avg_per_month)                            
    print("Total Average UPI Transaction-In in last 3 months : ", total_Avg_of_3_Months)
```

Result I got:

```
--------------

Average UPI Transaction-In per month :
          No of UPI Transaction  UPI TransferIn amt
Date                                             
Jul-18                      1              6984.0
Aug-18                      0                 NaN
Sep-18                      2              1780.0
Oct-18                      1              3000.0
--------------
Total Average UPI Transaction-In in last 3 months :  2390.0
--------------
```

I want the average to be calculated between Jul, Sep, Oct currently Its been calculated for Sep and Oct even when I wrote `last("3M")`.

Expected result:

```
--------------
Total Average UPI Transaction-In in last 3 months :  3921.33333
--------------
```

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of what you want to obtain would be easier rather than having to follow your code which appears to not be doing what you want

Comment: Which average values do you expect? Can you put those specific values in your question?

Comment: @SandervandenOord : I have edited my question for easy understanding can you please check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s rows and get last 3 by [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
Avg_of_3_Month = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M'))
                    .mean()
                    .dropna(subset=['UPI TransferIn amt'])
                    .tail(3))

total_Avg_of_3_Months = Avg_of_3_Month['UPI TransferIn amt'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Jezrael's answer is great. If you'd like to do it for multiple periods backwards, you can do this by calculating the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) mean:

```
your_data = [{'UPI TransferIn amt': 3000.0, 'date': '11-10-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 560.0, 'date': '25-09-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 3000.0, 'date': '14-09-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}, {'UPI TransferIn amt': 6984.0, 'date': '09-07-2018', 'No of UPI Transaction': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)

df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('M')
group = df.groupby('period')['UPI TransferIn amt'].mean()
average_3months = group.rolling(window=3, center=False).mean()
```